# Initialize array of struct variables - C

Tags: c

I have this array of structs in C:

```
struct Stream_Bufer {
    int size_;
    int capacity_max;
    int p_read;
    int p_write;
    char data_[320000]; 
} stream_buffer_[30];
```

But if I make `int capacity_max = 320000;` I will get the error: "data member initializer is not allowed". One way to initialize, that I found, is:

```
for(int i = 0; i<30;i++){
    stream_buffer_[i].capacity_max = 320000;
}
```

Any "clean" way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason in your code for `capacity_max` to have a value that would not be not 320000? At first sight, since the `data_` member has a constant size, you probably should use a constant instead.

Comment: To have a value that allow me to control the remaining size of the buffer, when I write in them. @SirDarius

Comment: Is your for() loop at global scope? (in C, code is not allowed outside a function, even not in initialisers)

Comment: @joop No. It is inside of a function.

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c99` (for GCC) ? Otherwise: declare the `i` outside the for() loop;

Comment: @joop I think you misread the question, OP's code is correct

Comment: Your solution is the best one. It's also possible to write .... `= { .capacity_max = 320000, .capacity_max = 320000, .capacity_max = 320000, .capacity_max = 320000, ` etc. up to 30 entries but that is tedious

Answer (score -2):

Works here, even in c89 mode:

```
void do_init(void)
{
int ii;

for(ii = 0; ii<30;ii++){
    stream_buffer_[ii].capacity_max = 320000;
        }

}
```

---

But, if you want to get rid of the duplicated constants, you could use:

```
struct Stream_Bufer {
    int size_;
    int capacity_max;
    int p_read;
    int p_write;
    char data_[320000];
} stream_buffer_[30];

#define COUNTOF(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a)[0])

void do_init(void) 
{
int ii;

for(ii = 0; ii< COUNTOF(stream_buffer_); ii++){
        stream_buffer_[ii].capacity_max = sizeof stream_buffer_[ii].data_;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thats my suggestion...

Answer (score -2):

For gnu C compiler you can use this way:

```
   struct data {
     int a;
     int b;
   } data[2] = {{ .b = 1 }, { .b = 2 }};
```

Comment: The question is about initializing an array of 30 structs

Comment: Designated initializers is a feature of C99, GCC provides this feature as a non-standard extension for C90. In other words, unless you are exclusively using C99 compliant compilers, this code is not portable across toolchains. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html.  Also, this method doesn't scale well for an array of structures.

Comment: Yes. 30 structure. I suggest to use include preprocesor directive and Python script to generate array of structure of data.